# How to calculate null space of a matrix in R so that the resulting vectors show basic variables in terms of free variables in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix A1 and I want to calculate it's null space.

```
A1=matrix(c(1,1,2,3,2,1,1,3,1,4),nrow=2,ncol=5,byrow =TRUE)



    [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    1    2    3    2
[2,]    1    1    3    1    4
```

I have using the function 'nullspace' from the package 'pracma'.

```
nullspace(matrix(c(1,1,2,3,2,1,1,3,1,4),nrow=2,ncol=5,byrow =TRUE))
```

and the result I am getting is

```
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,] -0.53530338 -0.53530338 -0.6117753
[2,]  0.23344278 -0.76655722  0.5525060
[3,]  0.68910778  0.02244112 -0.4505435
[4,] -0.07744944  0.25588390  0.1019625
[5,] -0.42200333  0.24466334  0.3272343
```

But when I am solving it manually, the result I am getting is

```
            [,1]        [,2]       [,3]
[1,]         -1          -7          2
[2,]          1           0          0
[3,]          0           2         -2
[4,]          0           1          0
[5,]          0           0          1
```

How can I get the second answer using R codes?
I cant find any package for this.

Comment: Nullspace results would not be expected to be unique. Have you demonstrated that these two results define distinct spaces? I think not.

Comment: I saw it on this video
https://www.khanacademy.org/math/linear-algebra/vectors-and-spaces/null-column-space/v/dimension-of-the-null-space-or-nullity

Comment: No.. these results define the same null space. Just wanted to know if I can get the answer like I calculated manually or given in the video.

Answer (score 2):

Have a close read on this Q & A: [Solve homogenous system Ax = 0 for any m * n matrix A in R (find null space basis for A)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43223579/4891738).

The `NullSpace` function in the answer does exactly what you are look for.

```
## Your matrix
A1 <- matrix(c(1,1,2,3,2,1,1,3,1,4),nrow=2,ncol=5,byrow =TRUE)

## get NullSpace from the linked Q & A yourself

## call NullSpace
X <- NullSpace(A1)

round(X, 15)
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]   -7    2   -1
#[2,]    0    0    1
#[3,]    2   -2    0
#[4,]    1    0    0
#[5,]    0    1    0
```

Answer (score 1):

The representation of the nullspace as column vectors is not unique so the fact that they are not the same set of vectors does not mean they represent different spaces.

In fact, the two solutions represent the same vector space.  Converting both to orthogonal projections we see that they are the same so they project onto the same space hence `m1` and `m2` span the same space.

```
library(pracma)

# manual
Lines <- "
     -1          -7          2
      1           0          0
      0           2         -2
      0           1          0
      0           0          1"
m1 <- as.matrix(read.table(text = Lines))
colnames(m1) <- NULL

# pracma
m2 <- nullspace(A1)
```

### Projections

```
# projections
P1 <- m1 %*% solve(crossprod(m1)) %*% t(m1)
P2 <- m2 %*% solve(crossprod(m2)) %*% t(m2)

all.equal(P1, P2)
## [1] TRUE
```

We can also calculate the projection directly from `A1` and verify that it is equal to these as well (using the fact that the perp of the space spanned by the range of the transpose of a matrix spans that matrix's nullspace):

```
P0 <- diag(5) - t(A1) %*% solve(crossprod(t(A1))) %*% A1
all.equal(P0, P1)
## [1] TRUE
```

### Reduced Row Echelon Form

The reduced row echelon form (`rref` in pracma) of the transpose of `m1` and `m2` are also unique and the rowspace of each spans the nullspace of `A1` since the rowspaces of `t(m1)` and `t(m2)` do.

```
all.equal(rref(t(m1)), rref(t(m2)), check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE

A1 %*% t(rref(t(m1)))  # gives 0 
##              [,1]         [,2] [,3]
## [1,] 5.551115e-17 5.551115e-17    0
## [2,] 1.110223e-16 1.110223e-16    0
```

The common value can be computed via:

```
t(rref(t(m1)))
```

giving:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]  1.0  0.0  0.0
[2,]  0.0  1.0  0.0
[3,]  0.0  0.0  1.0
[4,] -0.2 -0.2 -0.2
[5,] -0.2 -0.2 -0.7
```

### Converting m2 to m1

In the comments it is asked to convert `m2` into `m1`.  It appears that `m1` is the rref form but with rows and columns reversed so defining a function which reverses both and then transposes we have:

```
revt <- function(m) t(m[nrow(m):1, ncol(m):1])
all.equal(revt(rref(revt(m2))), m1, check.attributes = FALSE)
## [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thankyou for this elaborate answer. I understood quite a things from it. But I wanted to show my base variables in terms of free variables. Through m1, it is quite easy to show. So is there any way to convert m2 directly into m1?

Comment: See added sections.